# ldap_add symfony : server is unwilling to perform

Tags: php, ldap, symfony4

I need to add new entries in a Active Directory on Windows Server 2012 that I have in a Virtual Machine.

I'm on a Symfony 4 project using the Ldap Component bundle : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html

According to this documentation, I applied the following code:

```
####################
####  Form Add  ####
####################
        $entry = new Entry('CN=' . $infos->getCn() . ',' . $infos->getCheminAD(), [
            'middleName'                    =>          [$infos->getService()],
            'info'                          =>          [$infos->getTypeEquipement()],
            'initials'                       =>         [$infos->getNoeudDestination()],
            'sAMAccountName'                =>          [$infos->getSAMAccountName()],
            'cn'                            =>          [$infos->getCn()],
            'sn'                            =>          [$infos->getNom()],
            'givenName'                     =>          [$infos->getPrenom()],
            'displayName'                   =>          [$infos->getNomAffiche()],
            'employeeNumber'                =>          [$infos->getNumeroBadge()],
            'streetAddress'                 =>          [$infos->getBatiment()],
            'postOfficeBox'                 =>          [$infos->getEtage()],
            'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'    =>          [$infos->getBureau()],
            'objectClass' => ['inetOrgPerson']
        ]);

        $load = $ldap->save($management->getNomSite(), $entry);

##################################
#### Methode on class Service ####
##################################

    public function save($locate, $entry) {

        $connexion = $this->getConnexionLDAP(strtolower($locate));

        $ldap = Ldap::create('ext_ldap', array(
            'host' => $connexion['ip'],
        ));
        $ldap->bind($connexion['login'], $connexion['password']);

        $entryManager = $ldap->getEntryManager();
        $add = $entryManager->add($entry);

        return $add;
    }
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Could not add entry "CN=1,OU=FONCTIONNEL,OU=Users_visible,OU=Users,OU=Telephony,OU=Service,DC=ff,DC=STEP,DC=entreprise,DC=fr": Server is unwilling to perform.
```

I completely discover how Active Directory works, I read a lot of things on google to find a solution. But I'm completely lost, I don't understand what I'm reading (context out of Ldap Component of Symfony) and despite my attempts to try to apply cross solutions, I'm still in the incomprehension since 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It turns out that the DA VM I have is a copy of the original, which depends on other structures.

My copy is over 180 days old. So the DA is locked. So I made a new VM, everything works perfectly.